# How to add a simple text through an arrow break between nodes in tikzicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-arrows

I guess I need to define a different node style for this arrow break.

```
\documentclass[border=3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance = 5cm, thick,
 every node/.style = {rectangle, minimum width= 30mm, rounded corners=20pt,  font = \Large\sffamily, black,
top color = green!40!white, bottom color = green!20!white,drop shadow, minimum height = 2.5cm}]
\node (SWGDAM) {\textbf{SWGDAM}};
\node (42)        [right = of SWGDAM]  {4.2};
\draw [->] (SWGDAM) -- (42);
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't produce the image above, is this intentional? I'm referring to the node styles.

Comment: Yes, the above image is what I am asking on how to produce.

Comment: search for `mark connection node` in the pgf manual

Comment: @percusse, thank you for tip. I wasn't aware of it . Use of `decoration.markings` doesn't escape node styles, which are determined by `every node/.style` (concerning my answer and OP comment below it). Beside this, its use is more complex as it is proposed in both answers.

Comment: @Zarko I didn't understand your comment. Do you want to keep it or overwrite it in the text node?

Comment: @percusse, I understand you that you suggest to use library `decoration.markings` for text in arrows connecting two nodes. In my response I consider OP's comment below my answer and try to emphasize, that declaration `every node/.style = {...}` is employed to every node in picture, regardless if  it is hidden in `label`, `pin` or in `decoration`. Do I misunderstand your comments?

Comment: @Zarko I didn't have any comments I just gave an alternative :) I really don't get it. Do you want to reset the every node style?

Comment: Yes, however only in definition of style for nodes in arrows, something like this: `\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={...},txt/.style={<reset every node style>, <options for txt>},] ...`. I'm not aware, if this is possible.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I would to do reproduce that image:

- Use the actual colors with some RGB definition.
- Use the `arrows.meta` library. `arrows` is still supported, but it's deprecated.
- I changed some styling in the nodes to be more faithful. Also, this is a matter of preference, but I'd advise against using bold *and* large font together.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows.meta}

\definecolor{topgreen}{RGB}{242,255,225}
\definecolor{botgreen}{RGB}{220,253,174}
\definecolor{bordercol}{RGB}{158,174,125}
\definecolor{arrowcolor}{RGB}{74,126,186}

\tikzset{
    box/.style={draw=bordercol, rectangle, font=\sffamily, top color=topgreen, bottom color=botgreen, drop shadow, minimum width=2cm, inner ysep=4pt},
    myarr/.style={-{Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 5]}, arrowcolor},
    nodarr/.style={midway, fill=white, anchor=center, text=black, font=\sffamily}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=4cm]

\node[box] (SWGDAM) {SWGDAM};
\node[box, right = of SWGDAM] (42) {4.2};

\draw[myarr] (SWGDAM) -- (42) node[nodarr] {TEXT};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ,Thanks, this is so professional. The problem is that this is part of a bigger picture. I was thinking to keep my every node style and find a way to add a simple plain TEXT and arrow break between the two nodes only.

Comment: @Reza try renaming the box style to every node again, and it should still work, because the node style on the arrow should overwrite it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing, that you like to obtain something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shadows}

 \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 5cm, thick,
every node/.style = {font = \Large\sffamily, text=black},
box/.style = {rectangle, draw=green,
              minimum width= 30mm, minimum height = 12mm, %rounded corners=20pt,  
              top color = green!40!white, bottom color = green!20!white,
              drop shadow} 
                    ]
\node (SWGDAM) [box] {SWGDAM};
\node (42)     [box,right=of SWGDAM] {4.2};
\draw[->] (SWGDAM) -- node[fill=white] {TEXT} (42);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

so, regarding text in middle of arrow, you wasn't so far away, but your node style was wrong. You need two different nodes style ...

**Addendum:**
A variation of above proposition. This time with more fancy arrow, which is discontinued in place for text. With this you can have different color of background (this become handy in slide presentation, for example with `beamer`).

```
\documentclass[border=3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, shadows}

 \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 5cm, thick,
every node/.style = {font = \Large\sffamily, text=black},
       box/.style = {rectangle, draw=gray,
                     minimum width= 30mm, minimum height = 12mm,
                     top color = green!40!white, bottom color = green!20!white,
                     drop shadow},
       txt/.style = {rectangle, inner ysep=1pt, fill=white, sloped},
     arrow/.style = {draw=gray,line width=1mm, -{Triangle[]}},
                    ]
\node (SWGDAM) [box] {SWGDAM};
\node (42)     [box,right=of SWGDAM] {4.2};
\path (SWGDAM) to node[txt] (swg42) {TEXT} (42);
% real line with sloped text in the middle
\draw[arrow] (SWGDAM) -- (swg42) -- (42);
    \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is good. Thanks. But is there any way that I can keep my previous node style and just define a box for the TEXT?

Comment: @Reza, you mean to preserve definition for `every  node` and separately for TEXT? No this is not possible (at least not simple). When you ones define some options/attributes to all nodes id not easy or even possible to erase then first and than define new one.

Comment: One possible solution for what you like to have in code is use of scope, for example: `\begin{scope}[every node/.style={box}] \node (SWGDAM)   {SWGDAM}; ... \end{scope}`.